# Creating a Unique Key in R for time series data based on a binary starttime and endtime columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot lane data for trips taken in driving studies. The data-set looks like this:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fw5h.png)

Using the following code, I was able to create plots for each trip

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

LaneData <- read.csv(file="c:\\Users\\jasonzb\\Desktop\\Cars overtaking trucks Project\\Honda Image\\Truck Overpassing Event Device 10150.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
LaneData <- cbind(LaneData[,1:3], LaneData[,7:8])

#rename first column
colnames(LaneData)[1] <- "device"

#Create segment to split data by
LaneData$SplitID <- seq.int(nrow(LaneData))
LaneData$SplitID = round(LaneData$SplitID, digits = -4)

#melt the data
LaneData <-melt(LaneData, id=c("device", "trip", "time", "SplitID"))

#Create levels for SplitID
LaneData$SplitID = factor(LaneData$SplitID)

for (i in levels(LaneData$SplitID)){
   LaneData_temp <- subset(LaneData, LaneData$SplitID == i)  
   print(ggplot(LaneData_temp, aes(LaneData_temp$value, LaneData_temp$time, col =LaneData_temp$variable)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ trip, scales = "free"))
}
```

This results in plots that look like this:
[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtZpV.png)

For the plot on the right (Trip 5820), everything looks fine. However, for the plot on the right (Trip 5813), there are several time series events in different intervals combined due to gaps in the data that looks like this: [Dataset: Time series Break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSOuI.png)

Is there a way to create a unique key to separate the changes in the timestamps so each segment of time series data could be plotted separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a new column as multiplies to the *time* variable. Then run a multiple variable `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`. As example:

```
time <- c(523490 + seq(0, 70, 10), 764350 + seq(0, 50, 10))
time
# [1] 523490 523500 523510 523520 523530 523540 523550 523560 764350 764360 764370 764380 764390 764400

# THOUSAND MULTIPLIERS
time_grp <- as.integer(time / 10000)
time_grp
# [1] 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 76 76 76 76 76 76

# TEN-THOUSAND MULTIPLIERS
time_grp <- as.integer(time / 100000)
time_grp
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

To integrate into current code, replace last `for` loop with `by` to split data frames into subsets for plotting:

```
...
by(LaneData, LaneData$SplitID, function(sub) {
   sub$time_grp <- as.integer(sub$time / 10000)

   ggplot(sub, aes(value, time, col=variable)) + geom_point() +
       facet_wrap(trip ~ time_grp, scales = "free")
       # TRY: facet_grid(. ~ time_grp + trip, scales = "free")
})
```